# XMLHttpRequest JSON.parse()

Tags: javascript, json, xml, for-loop, xmlhttprequest

still quiet new to coding

I need to make a XMLHttpRequest and then use JSON.parse to retrieve an object. Once I have the object need to display the object according to its "type" as either bigheading, heading or paragraph.

Without using JSON.parse:

```
             var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

            xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://****/chapters/?n=0",false);

            xmlhttp.send();

            result=xmlhttp.responseText;

            document.getElementById("sec1").innerHTML=result;
```

i get the following

```
           {"data": " PART ONE ", "type": "bigheading"}
```

With JSON.parse:

```
               var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

            xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://xxxxxx/chapters/?n=0",false);

            xmlhttp.send();

            result=xmlhttp.responseText;

            JSONresult = JSON.parse(result);

            document.getElementById("sec1").innerHTML=JSONresult;
```

Result is:

```
      [object Object]
```

Also need to implement some type of FOR LOOP for the end of the URL (n=0-38) as this represents the number of sections. I can only display one section at a time. Not sure how to implement a FOR loop within a URL. THANK YOU!

Comment: why cant' you have a single request that returns all the 38 values as an array

Comment: Actually just needs to show the first 5 sections/values of the array, and then one every after that. Just the criteria I was given. But I have no idea how to use a counter/loop within the URL link

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
var section = document.getElementById("sec1");
section.className += ' ' + JSONResult.type;    // Style the section by the type
section.innerHTML = JSONResult.data;           // Fill in the section with the data
```